# Is there geocoding "undo" button in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, error, geocoding

Here's the map in question: https://mwhite.cartodb.com/tables/where_good_neighbors_work

Our map had been working beautifully for several months, but when updates were attempted recently, all of our locations were somehow changed to the same longitude/latitude point. Basically, I want to know if we need to go in and fix all of them by hand (I cannot get geocoding to work anymore using any of my table's location criteria, though it worked fine before. I strongly suspect using geocoding might have caused this problem in the first place, but I can't say for sure as I was not the one who used it this time).

Anyway. If there is some way of automating the long/lat fix, or possibly using a proverbial “back button” to restore the geodata we had before, I would like to try those options before going through the labor-intensive process of correcting them all by hand.

Comment: Have you contacted CartoDB directly?

Comment: Yeah, twice. Not getting a response so far.

Comment: Hi, everyone. Heard back from CartoDB. Just thought I'd share their response in case anyone else had this problem. Basically, they said to go to our table and delete the cartodb_georef_status column. Apparently we need to do this every time we want to try to georeference the table again. The also added that there is no undo button. Hmm, maybe I should make a back-up in Excel?

Incidentally, we won't be using geotracking anymore because of this issue. We're inputting GPS coordinates manually from here on out. Too bad...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but CartoDB doesn't have an "undo button". A great practical way of work is having "backups" when you are doing a 'big change', and also you could compare it.